# When using surfaceview, images are not visible but they are drawing on view in android

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am drawing some bitmaps in canvas in which my class is 
extended by view, then everything is working fine but I found that 
efficiency is lacking in this. So i have searched for other 
alternatives and found that we need to extend class to surfaceview 
inorder to increase efficiency. So at present I am drawing bitmaps 
using surfaceview. But here is the problem, when I changed and run the 
program I am unable to see the bitmaps but the onDraw() is called and user touches are being handled by my view. I 
have done some searching in this but couldnt found anything. Can you 
please let me know eventhough the images are being draw on to the 
view, why the images are not being displayed???

Thanks